# ThymeLeaf: Cannot display view after calling endpoint

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, web, thymeleaf

I am trying to call a REST endpoint and then display a ThymeLeaf template:

The Endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/devices")
public String getDeviceDetailU(Model model) {
  List<FinalDevice> devices = deviceService.getAll();
  model.addAttribute("devices", devices);
  return "deviceList";  
}
```

For the endpoint I tried returning /deviceList, /deviceList.html, deviceList.html.

Whenever I navigate to the endpoint, I simply get the string that was returned.

Here is the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <body>
Hello World!
    </body>
</html>
```

While I understand, at this point, it will not display the list, I just want to be forwarded to the template.

If I go to localhost:8080/deviceType I display that template.  This to me indicates it is not a security or configuration issue.

Any ideas?

This should all work according to this [tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kttfBthzIPI)

Comment: You probably have `@RestController` instead of just a `@Controller`.  If you want templates to be rendered, you need to use `@Controller`.  `@RestController` means that all your `@Mappings` simple serialize the return value and output it as json or xml (which is why you are seeing the string `deviceList` instead of the template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `@RestController` instead of just a `@Controller`.

If you want templates to be rendered you need to use `@Controller`.  `@RestController` means that all your `@Mappings` simply serialize the return value and output it as json or xml (which is why you are seeing the string deviceList instead of the template).

Comment: May I know if using @Controller will the app still be considered a a RESTful webservice app ?